# ltspice - how to tell long from stuck simulation

Tags: ltspice

If a simulation in LT Spice has been running too long, is there a way of telling it has got stuck as opposed to it running correctly but slowly due to complex circuitry?

Comment: Are you using "probe" to collect measurements?

Comment: My question was a general one. When I simulate, I will run the simulation and when it is finished, I will click on a node/component lead in the schematic to see a voltage/current. I often then re-run the simulation with changed component values, so these voltage/current probes are assumed by LT spice. If these are the probes you refer to.

Comment: Try running LTSpice not using probe but using the transient analysis configure screen and selecting a node explicitly beforehand. You should then see it accumulating a waveform from left to right as it progresses.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the speed of the simulation in the bottom status bar.. If you see an approximately constant speed of e.g. several µs/s, it is simulating alright. If it got stuck due to lacking convergence, it is probably at a few fs/s or shows no speed at all, but instead some internal steps that help reaching convergence.